# Vue shows error log in Karma, but Karma not showing a failed test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, chai, karma-mocha

I am attempting to write unit tests for Vue components on our new project.

I am using Karma with Mocha + Chai, and PhantomJS as a browser.

My test command `cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start client/test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run`

Please let me know if you need to see the karma conf or the code of the component itself. (I've left it out as it is long and tricky to trim, and I'm *pretty* sure the issue isn't with the component).

My test code is as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SendEmail from '@/components/SendEmail'

describe('SendEmail.vue', () => {
  it('should render correct contents', (done) => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(SendEmail)
    const vm = new Constructor({
      propsData: {
        email: '{{test}}',
        template: {},
      }
    }).$mount()
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.section h5').textContent)
    .to.equal('Template Variables')
    done()
  })
  it('should create inputs based off context in input', (done) => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(SendEmail)
    const vm = new Constructor({
      propsData: {
        email: '<p> hello bob {{test}} </p>',
        template: {},
      }
    }).$mount()
    vm._watcher.run()
    Vue.nextTick(()=>{
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.input-field #test')).to.be.null;
        done()
    })
  })
})
```

The problem is that regardless of whether the "it should create inputs based off context in input" test is `expect...to.be.null` or `expect...to.not.be.null`, the test displays as "passed" in Karma.

**expect...to.be.null**

```
 cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start client/test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run

03 01 2018 16:15:50.637:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
03 01 2018 16:15:50.639:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
03 01 2018 16:15:50.665:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
03 01 2018 16:15:50.949:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket SD3YIlvnm7q7SpXMAAAA with id 69225830

  SendEmail.vue
    ✓ should render correct contents
    ✓ should create inputs based off context in input

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.053 secs / 0.012 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

**expect...to.be.not.null**

```
cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start client/test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run

03 01 2018 16:15:29.471:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
03 01 2018 16:15:29.473:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
03 01 2018 16:15:29.509:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
03 01 2018 16:15:30.105:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket AIFlufSWBVUaXMD7AAAA with id 50204600

  SendEmail.vue
    ✓ should render correct contents
    ✓ should create inputs based off context in input

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.03 secs / 0.019 secs)
TOTAL: 2 SUCCESS
```

Here's the weird bit: *vue appears to be throwing an error for the failed assertion*, which is displayed as an error log for the **expect...to.be.null** test (seeing as that IS the state of reality - the result is not null).

```
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "AssertionError: expected <input placeholder="" id="test" type="text"> to be null"'
ERROR LOG: AssertionError{message: 'expected <input placeholder="" id="test" type="text"> to be null', showDiff: false, actual: <input placeholder="" id="test" type="text">, expected: undefined, stack: 'AssertionError@http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/calebjay/Documents/internal-admin/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:9320:24
assert@http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/calebjay/Documents/internal-admin/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:239:31
http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/calebjay/Documents/internal-admin/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:1087:16
propertyGetter@http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/calebjay/Documents/internal-admin/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae:7784:33
http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?a3d01b46a2e8d6dea408b15b7f752ca119ad7183:23805:63
http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?a3d01b46a2e8d6dea408b15b7f752ca119ad7183:5405:16
flushCallbacks@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?a3d01b46a2e8d6dea408b15b7f752ca119ad7183:5326:14', line: 243, sourceURL: 'http://localhost:9876/absolute/home/calebjay/Documents/internal-admin/node_modules/chai/chai.js?40e7aa72e9665366bfd82579520de4fb0754dfae'}
```

**How can I make Karma catch these failed assertions and show them as failed tests, rather than have them appear as vue error logs?**

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the cause of your problem, but it's still an error worth fixing. If your test contains an async operation (in this case, `nextTick`), you need to declare a `done` parameter, and then call `done()` when your async operation && assertions are finished. Chai will detect whether or not this parameter is declared. If it detects it, Chai will know your test is done when `done()` is called.

```
it('should create inputs based off context in input', done => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(SendEmail)
    const vm = new Constructor({
      propsData: {
        email: '<p> hello bob {{test}} </p>',
        template: {},
      }
    }).$mount()
    vm._watcher.run()
    Vue.nextTick(()=>{
        expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.input-field #test')).to.be.null;
        done();
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, I had been trying to get the `done()` bit right but didn't realize it was an argument for the `it()` function. 

However, I still get the same issue. This time the tests actually fail, but the reason is "timeout" to karma, and vue logs the actual mocha/chai output (or karma? Not sure).